# Protractor - testing an Angular form with dynamically populated inputs

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to write an e2e test for my angular application, and in particular a form that has 3 select inputs on. The test will need to involve picking random options from these selects. The first select is already populated with data, but the other 2 selects asynchronously populate when the one before has been selected, so they are dependant on each other.

The select inputs also use ng-disabled and only enable when there are options available as per their ng-repeat expressions.

I am using the page object approach with my tests, and so am trying to make some utility functions to achieve the random selection behaviour I need in my tests:

**Page Object:**

```
    this.selectRandomCustomer = function() {
    var option,
      randomIndex;
    this.customerSelect.click();
    this.customerSelectOptions.count().then(function(count) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
      option = element(by.repeater('customer in vm.customers').row(randomIndex));
      option.click();
    });
  };

  this.selectRandomOrder = function() {
    if(this.orderSelect.isEnabled()===true) {
      var option,
        randomIndex;
      this.orderSelect.click();
      this.orderSelectOptions.count().then(function(count) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        option = element(by.repeater('order in vm.orders').row(randomIndex));
        option.click();
      });
    }
  };
```

Given that the `orderSelect` can only be selected once populated with options after choosing an option from the `customerSelect`, I wondered about hooking into the promise returned when calling `this.customerSelectOptions.count()`, so calling `this.selectRandomOrder`, but it seems this is undefined as I get an error from protractor saying it cannot find the `selectRandomOrder` function.

Right now I can only get the first select to pick an option since it's always populated on the initial page load.

Also, I'm unsure whether using `isEnabled()` is actually working for me, as I am certain this should be returning true for my second input, but if I console log this out, I see false. Does this not work with `ng-disabled`?

What are the best practices for dealing with inputs on a form that wont initially be populated with data and waiting for angular to fetch and populate any available options?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have got this to working using a call to `getAttribute()` checking for the presence of the `disabled` property instead.

So from my spec file in an `it` block I can call

```
page.customerSelect.getAttribute('disabled').then(function(result){
    if(!result) {
        page.selectRandomCustomer();
    }
});

page.orderSelect.getAttribute('disabled').then(function(result){
    if(!result) {
        page.selectRandomOrder();
    }
});
```

Ideally what I'd like to be able to do is to call the selectRandomOrder after clicking the option in the selectRandomCustomer:

```
this.selectRandomCustomer = function() {
    var option,
        randomIndex;
    this.customerSelect.click();
    this.customerSelectOptions.count().then(function(count) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        option = element(by.repeater('customer in vm.customer').row(randomIndex));
        option.click();
        //Like to be able to call selectRandomOrder but only after angular has finished performing AJAX request for data and received response
    });
};

this.selectRandomOrder = function() {
    var option,
        randomIndex;
    this.orderSelect.click();
    this.orderSelectOptions.count().then(function(count) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        option = element(by.repeater('order in vm.orders').row(randomIndex));
        option.click();
    });
};
```

I did try calling `this.selectRandomOrder` immediately after the `option.click()` but I get an error saying no such function, it seems `this` is not accessible from inside the returned promise function callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one major problem in the posted code:

```
if(this.orderSelect.isEnabled()===true) {
```

Here `isEnabled()` *returns a promise*. You have to resolve it to check it's value:

```
var self = this;  // saving the page object reference
this.orderSelect.isEnabled().then(function (isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        var option,
            randomIndex;
        self.orderSelect.click();
        self.orderSelectOptions.count().then(function(count) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
            option = element(by.repeater('order in vm.orders').row(randomIndex));
            option.click();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah yes ok, you say at least one major problem. So what else should I be taking care to do here? Thanks

Comment: @mindparse it depends..what is the current state of the problem? Have you made it work? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did get it working but using getAttribute() instead of the isEnabled(). I think I read something about how isEnabled doesnt work well with ng-disabled. Anyway, see my update as ideally I want to call further functions from within each promise callback to chain calls to functions in my page object. That way I can just have one utility function called something like 'selectOptions' which I can call from my test spec file.